# MGSVPP: Farming Staff

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I accidently dismissed all my staffs of ~700 persons down to just 6: Huey, Miller, Ocelot, Quiet, Silent Basilisk, Ziang Tan. Whom are locked, if not they'd probably gone too. Yeah, I know, stupid me.

The last couple of days I've been grinding to raise my staff count back, even recruiting low ranks with all E stats. Before that I dismissed anyone who doesn't have at least one A, and only recruited ones with at least one yellow stat (i.e. A+ up).

Currently I'm at 254 persons. Still a lot to go, even more if I want to go back at my standard of at least one A.

So, any suggestion how to quickly raise my staff count? Currently my method is free roaming with Quiet and have her stuns all soldiers with Cover Me/Guilty Butterfly combination.

Comment: IIRC I found plenty of folks while grinding for S rank completion in the missions, but it's been a long time since I played MGS5.

Comment: @pboss3010 Yeah, just got my console last April since I was so bored stuck at home. The last time I really into gaming was around NFS: Carbon/GTA IV. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah! There's actually an excellent way to farm staff in MGS:TPP. Replay mission 16: Traitor's Caravan! In this mission you have to find a truck, defeat the spawned Skulls, and fulton the truck back to Mother Base. The truck always spawns in the same spot in the back of the airfield so it is easy to perform this mission, and thus the farming, quickly.

Partway through the mission you'll need to fight four Skull agents. After the Skulls have been slain all guards at the airfield and the several surround outposts will be knocked asleep for several minutes by the Skull's powers. Using D-Dog these sleeping soldiers can be identified and easily and safely fultoned back to Mother Base. Once soldiers start to wake from their slumber you can return to the airfield to easily extract the truck and finish the mission

When doing this you should fulton ALL soldiers due to a quirk of how soldiers' ranks are generated. The more staff you have at Mother Base the stronger the staff you find out in the field. It seems counterintuitive but only collecting high-ranking soldiers will mean that the rest won't be as strong. Every D-level soldier you fulton back slightly increases the odds of finding an A-rank later. This means it isn't in your best interest to dismiss weak soldiers either; instead keep them in staff roster even if they aren't assigned to a facility.

Comment: DeFeAt ThE sPaWnEd SkUlLs.

Man, those skulls always give me the creeps. I'm still avoiding replaying missions that involves them :D

Anyways, your suggestion seems legit. Just watched a couple of YouTube videos which recommend the exact same thing.

Comment: What’s good about this method is because there isn’t much of a penalty if you go loud - enemies will still be asleep afterwards. This means you can bring your toughest body armor and heaviest machine gun to defeat the skulls